# Measuring input resistance to a MOSFET/BJT amplifier

Tags: bjt, resistance, emitter-follower

How would one go about measuring the resistance of a Emitter follower in PSPICE?

Comment: PSPICE is a simulator, so you're not really measuring anything.  At best it can report what it thinks a real circuit would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always by using the Ohms law: \$R = \frac{dU}{dI}\$